# Will gRPC be a good choice, and is a gracefully termination possible from client side

Tags: java, streaming, grpc

We are trying to create a service for subscribing to events, and have looked at various technologies for solving this.
On the surface `gRPC` looks like it could possibly fulfill our needs, but we have stumbled upon some challanges.

My thoughts were that we could have the client choose the subscription (IDs etc) and then call the `gRPC` service operation with server streaming. This operation would create the subscription, start polling the source of events and then start pushing them back to the client(indefinitely).

The problem occurs when we want to shutdown the client or change the subscription. I have not been able to find a suitable way of doing a gracefully stop of the push from the server. Does this exist? Or is `gRPC` not the best tech when the amounts of messages pushed from the server is unknown/indefinitely? Are there other technologies that will suit our needs better, that has the same kind of performance?

Answers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

gRPC could work well for your case.

The client could use half-close to notify server that the client is going away. The client would send the request initially, without half-closing the stream.  It would half-close the stream when it going to shutdown.  When the server receives half-close, it could stop sending and close the stream.  The client would wait for the stream to be completely closed before termination.

To make sure the client receives every event that server sends, you probably want the client to ack messages to the server on a regular basis.

Comment: Can you please guide how to keep the connection in client open so that further responses from streaming server can be received by client?

Comment: If you keep the stream alive, the connection will stay open. The stream will stay alive as long as the server doesn't call `StreamObserver.onCompleted()` or `StreamObserver.onError()`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please answer how to keep the C++ client open always for stream responses from server? It closes connection after 15 seconds automatically. And set_deadline on context is not working.